# .net core "The request filtering module is configured to deny a request where the query string is too long"

Tags: .net, .net-core, razor-pages

I received the above error when running an application based on .net core in which I'm trying to apply authentication and authorization. The error is displayed on the first page (the Index page) itself. It seems to be saying the ReturnURL query string parameter is too long. How to fix this error?

I tried the suggestions given on other Stack Overflow question. Which are suggesting to change the requestLimits parameter in the web.config file or the Maximum Query String value in IIS as given in the following links. But they did not work.

[other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636386/how-to-configure-the-web-config-to-allow-requests-of-any-length)

[other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532610/how-to-fix-error-the-request-filtering-module-is-configured-to-deny-a-request-w)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what the problem was.

I have this code in my Program.cs class.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});
```

Which adds authorization to all files. Which means the Index page required authorization. But for it to be displayed for the first time we need to AllowAnonymous. As in

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    //The code
}
```

So if you get this error and it says the returnURL is too long check whether the page has authorization which may not be obvious from the error message